# Weak- L^1 convergence and lower semicontinuity of an integral functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $f,f_n: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be positive functions. Suppose $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ as well as $f_n|v|^k \rightharpoonup f|v|^k$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for all $0\le k< 2$ (and I know for sure it can not happen for $k=2$). Moreover, the sequence satisfies
$$\sup_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f_n(v)(1+|v|^2) d\,v < \infty.$$

I have to show that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(v) |v|^2 d\,v \le \liminf_n \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f_n(v)|v|^2 d\,v$$

It should be easy but I can't figure out the exact argument.

It looks like an application of Fatou's lemma, but I don't have pointwise convergence. Maybe it is possible to extract a subsequence such that $f=\liminf_j f_{n_j}$ but I'm not sure.

I know that convexity is sufficient for weak lower semicontinuity when the domain of integration is of finite measure, but here is all $\mathbb{R^3}$. Is it something due to the linearity of the operator?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It think that the second condition implies that $f_n$ us uniformly integrable. If that is indeed the case, the Dunford-Pettis theorem may be the hammer you need for this nail.